# $resource success callback returning $promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-resource

Using Angular 1.2.14, $resource's success callback should return an object, but it sometimes gets a $promise. The node/express web service is returning null, but Angular interprets it as a $promise. When a non-null is returned from the web service, the success callback gets the object as expected.

```
$resource('/api/users/:userId/team').get({ userId: userId }, function(team) {
    console.log('team: ', team);                
}, function(err) {
    console.log('err: ', err);
});
```

The value of team (the parameter to the success callback) is:

```
$promise: Object
    catch: function (callback) {
    finally: function (callback) {
    then: function (callback, errback, progressback) {
    __proto__: Object
    $resolved: true
__proto__: Resource
    $delete: function (params, success, error) {
    $get: function (params, success, error) {
    $query: function (params, success, error) {
    $remove: function (params, success, error) {
    $save: function (params, success, error) {
    constructor: function Resource(value) {
    __proto__: Object
```

Why is the success callback getting a $promise and not an object?

Comment: When you say the server sometimes returns null, does it return with http 200 code? Are there any errors thrown by the browser?

Comment: Maybe instead of returning null you can return something more friendly . I'm not sure what you do in express, but in rails you can return a headers only response: [HTTP status code 204](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) This tells the browser "hey we received your request, but don't have anything to send back in the response, other than these headers".

Comment: @SunilD. My web server **is** returning HTTP 204, but Angular is providing the response as a promise, instead of null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the success callback getting a $promise and not an object?

Because it made a successful HTTP request and received a response which happened to be `null`. Returning `null` is not how we signal to an HTTP server that our value is invalid - rather, we return the appropriate status code to indicate failure - see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

> How do I fix it from the client?

Well, you didn't ask this, but I assume this is what you actually care about, since `$resource` returns a promise, you can transform it yourself, via a decorator for example.

If you don't need re-usability you can simply do:

```
$resource('/api/users/:userId/team').get({ userId: userId }).then(function(res){
    if(res === null) return $q.reject("Error, server returned null");
    return res;
}).then(function(team) {
    console.log('team: ', team);                
}, function(err) {
    console.log('err: ', err);
});
```

Otherwise, you can wrap it in a more general method:

```
function notNull(prom){
    return prom.then(function(res){
        if(res === null) return $q.reject("Error, got null);
        return res;
    });
};
```

Which would let you do:

```
notNull($resource('/api/users/:userId/team').get({ userId: userId })).then(function(res){
      // server returned not null.
}).catch(function(e){
     // returned null, or other server error, or error in previous then handler.
});
```

Comment: my web server is returning HTTP 204 to indicate that there is no content, but Angular is presenting the returned data as a completed promise instead of null which is what I expected. How to convert that completedPromise/HTTP204 into a null object within Angular?

Comment: To be (hopefully) clearer, the output from $resource contains the $promise and $resolved members which causes any common implementations of isEmpty() to return true when they should be returning false. My solution has been to manually strip these members from the returned result. Is there a better way?