# How to get object returned by POST method using angular $resource?

Tags: angularjs, post, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have the following POST method in my Web API Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Hotspot hotspot)
        {
            try
            {
                int id = await SomeMethod();
                return Ok(id);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {

                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

And then I make the POST request and try to get the **id**:

```
var hotspots = $resource('/api/adminhotspots', { save: { method: 'POST' } });
hotspots.save($scope.hotspot).$promise.then(function (id) {
     console.log(id);
});
```

Unfortunately, I get a **$promise object**. My console shows:

```
m
  $promise : d
  $resolved : true
```

I can check that the server sends the parameter correctly in the Network tab in my Developer Console. And it is correct, indeed.

Why doesn't the $resource catch the parameter and what can I do about it?

Thank YOU!

Comment: did you try to remove the .$promise. Because the save method already returns a promise

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I have, but then I get the following error: save().then() is not a function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have managed to detect the wrong point in my code, I'll post an answer myself so that others could be helped.

It seems that sending a primitive variable was the problem. The client packs the data received from the server into a $resource object and the primitive variable (**int** in my case) is lost.

The solution was to send the integer as an object. For the sake of simplicity I will only add some brackets to that variable just like in these lines:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Hotspot hotspot)
{
    try
    {
        int id = await SomeMethod();
        return Ok(new {id});
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {

        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
```

At the client the **id** can be obtained as such:

```
hotspots.save($scope.hotspot).$promise.then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this should works:

```
 var hotspots = $resource('/api/adminhotspots');
    hotspots.save($scope.hotspot,{}, function (response) {
         console.log(respose);
    });
```

Rememer that non-GET "class" actions have this parameters:

```
Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
```

Comment: Oh yes, I've also tried this, but I get the very same thing. The **response** object will be look just the same.

Comment: $scope.hotspot is a parameters or data to post? Check again the success function must be the 3rd parameter.

Comment: $scope.hotspot is the data to post, not the parameter. Anyway, as the parameters are optional, the function will clearly be interpreted as the [success] parameter.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599277/resource-success-callback-returning-promise seems like this is happening due to a null response from the server.

Comment: No, the response is not null, as I've already specified in the question text. The response contains the expected integer.